# How to declare flow types for REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, flowtype

=====EDIT=====

Thanks to @kalley I updated my declaration file and made a bit of progress. I don't have a linting error anymore, but I still can't get the type to be recognizes where I import them. I updated the content of the files above

=====end EDIT=====

I'm trying to create flow type for a REST API that I consume for a project I"m working on.

I'm running into an issues:
 the types are not being seen when i'm editing the source using the new type

Here is the file which contains the types (src/flow-typed/API.js)

```
// @flow

declare module "API" {
  //  type Error = {code:number, message:string};
  declare export type ImageJSON = {
    url: string,
    reference: string
  };

  declare export type CategoryJSON = {
    reference: number,
    name: string,
    slug: string,
    icon: ImageJSON,
    children: [],
    created_at: string
  };

  declare export type CompanyJSON = {
    reference: number,
    name: string,
    slug: string,
    email: string,
    occupational_medicine: string,
    psychology_of_work: string,
    logo: ImageJSON,
    categories: Array<CategoryJSON>,
    created_at: string
  };

  declare export type GetCompanyResponse = {
    error: Error,
    company: CompanyJSON
  };

  // declare export default GetCompanyResponse
}
```

I import the file this way

```
import typeof { GetCompanyResponse } from "../flow-typed/API";
```

I get the following flow error:

```
[flow] Named import from module `../flow-typed/WazzaAPI` (This module only has a default export. Did you mean `import GetCompanyResponse from ...`?)
```

If I import the file like so 
    import typeof GetCompanyResponse from "../flow-typed/API";

Then in the code I get an error saying the GetCompanyResponse does not have an error member:

```
.then((response: GetCompanyResponse) => {
    //check to see if there is an error
    if (response.error.code !== ERROR_CODE.noError) {
```

The error:

```
[flow] property `error` (Property not found in exports)
```

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: The file should start with `// @flow` That should fix your issue, but if not, you should at least get some useful feedback

Comment: Does it work when you use `import type` instead of `import typeof` (`typeof` should not be used for imports. Only when you actually need the type of an existing variable)?

Comment: @kalley If I use type instead of typeOf, then I get a flow error when I try to use GetCompanyResponse ie:  .then((response: GetCompanyResponse)   ====>     [flow] exports (Ineligible value used in/as type annotation (did you forget 'typeof'?) GetCompanyResponse)

Comment: Since you defined the module as `'API'`, you should be importing from that like: `import type { GetCompanyResponse } from 'API'`.

Comment: @Kalley, I tried that and the flow type then work fine if I remove the typeof. Unfortunately, I still get a Flow warning that the module can't be found and the app won't run. I get a module does not exists in module map at runtime too :(. If I leave the typeof decorator, then the type don't work :(

Comment: You might be better off just creating a type file that doesn't declare a module. I think the crux is that you don't have an actual module called `'API'`. Just create a file in your app that's like `api.js.flow` and just `export type` without the `declare module`. I didn't realize you didn't have a file that you're module was referencing (tunnel vision).